# How do I access the second level of an index when grouping by the first level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a pd.DataFrame df with a MultiIndex as index. When I group by the first level, how can I get the second level of the MultiIndex as an Index? The groupby object is

`gdf = df.groupby(level=['first_level])`.

I want to transform by a function that takes in a pd.DataFrame and outputs a pd.Series. The Input is supposed to be the pd.DataFrames with index the second level of the original MultiIndex, and the Ouput is supposed to be indexed by the first level of the original MultiIndex.

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do after `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using `get_group()` and reset the first_level index

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], [1, 2, 1, 2]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('first_level', 'second_level'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [10, 20, 30, 40]}, index=index)
print(df)

gdf = df.groupby(level='first_level')
gr_A = gdf.get_group('A')  # access first_level 'A'
gr_A = gr_A.reset_index(level='first_level', drop=True) # reset first_level index 
print(gr_A)
```

Or:

```
gdf = df.groupby(level='first_level')
gr_A = gdf.get_group('A').droplevel('first_level')
print(gr_A)
```

Output:

```
                          value
first_level second_level
A           1                10
            2                20
B           1                30
            2                40
              value
second_level
1                10
2                20
```

**EDIT:**

You can get a series and apply/transform any process:

Example1 (with apply):

```
result_series_A = df[df.index.get_level_values('first_level') == 'A']['value'].apply(lambda x: x * 2)
#result_series_A = df[df.index.get_level_values('first_level') == 'A']['value']  # with reset_index, get the data as series
result_series_A = result_series_A.reset_index(drop=True)
print(result_series_A)
```

Example2 (with transform):

```
df['transformed_value'] = df.groupby(level='first_level')['value'].transform(lambda x: x * 2)
result_series_A = df[df.index.get_level_values('first_level') == 'A']['transformed_value']
result_series_A = result_series_A.reset_index(drop=True)
print(result_series_A)
```

Output:

```
                          value
first_level second_level
A           1                10
            2                20
B           1                30
            2                40
0    20
1    40
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to transform by a function that takes in the DataFrames indexed by the second level, and outputs a Series? I am thinking of gdf.transform(func) with output a DataFrame indexed by the first level.

Comment: @user242318 yes, I updated the post (after the edit part). You can play with DF. I put some possibilities.